# How to get the maximum duration in Python List

Tags: python

How to get the maximum value of time or duration in Python List?

Basically, I have this list of duration:

** List **

```
z = [u'00:54', u'03:37', u'01:22:10', u'11:19', u'08:45', u'09:37', u'09:10', u'01:31', u'02:55', u'08:07']
```

And i use this code to get the max:

```
max_fail = max(z)
print(max_fail)
```

But the result is `11:19` which is wrong because I expected that `01:22:10` is the max value.

Any help ?

Comment: I can't understand. 01:22:10 > 11:19 !      11:19 is 00:11:19 ?

Comment: You are treating them as strings while finding max in them You should convert them into seconds first before doing that. Check my answer for an approach.

Comment: The list values indentation is totally wrong!!!

Comment: You can't provide `hh:mm` then one `hh:mm:ss`. Now you turned from a duration to only string indexation length. You've to decide if you will make the format `hh:mm` or `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @Dr.Xavier it would still remain a string even if OP provided all of them as `mm:ss` or all of them as `hh:mm:ss`. The fact that it represents hours, minutes and seconds for a max operation has to still be handled explicitly.

Comment: impossible!!!.. will give him a False Negative in long term and much data provided. There's lack into the data, itself. He/She has to provide 1 type of data, it can't be more than 1 type. Even if this's a stopwatch data. It has to has 3 aspect  `hh:mm:ss` even if the time it took was only 30 min and 26 sec ---> it has to be in this format `00:30:26` so, we can figure the right answer depending on global syntax, not a custom one for specific type or aspect!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are treating a `hh:mm:ss` or `mm:ss` time stamp as a string. This alphabetically sorts and gives precedence to 11 over 01. What you want to do is convert each timestamp into seconds and then check for max. Try this -

1. The `get_sec` function splits the strings and multiplies them with corresponding seconds. Using zip, I have handled variable lengths (meaning you can pass `hh:mm:ss` or `mm:ss` and it will still handle it.
2. You can use this with a lambda function to define a key for the max function.

```
z = [u'00:54', u'03:37', u'01:22:10', u'11:19', u'08:45', u'09:37', u'09:10', u'01:31', u'02:55', u'08:07']

def get_sec(time):
    parts = time.split(':')
    secs = [1,60,3600] #seconds in 1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour
    return sum([int(i)*j for i,j in zip(parts, secs)])

max(z, key=lambda x: get_sec(x))
```

```
'01:22:10'
```

Comment: It's working! how about to get the min value of duration?

Comment: just use `min(z, key=lambda x: get_sec(x))`

Comment: Also, do mark and upvote the answer if it worked for you, this encourages me to help you with your future questions :). Cheers!